# GridLayout created programmatically does not look the same as the GridLayout created in XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a grid of green tile the same as the XML file but programmatically:

```
     <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="389dp"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="6"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView25"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView23"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/green_tile" />

    </GridLayout>
```

The result when launching the app using XML look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pljkD.png

The result when adding Tile programmatically look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjhH5.png

I tried to do it programmatically but the UI does not look the same as using XML .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.grid);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * 6; i++) {
        GridLayout.LayoutParams param= new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f);
        param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,1f);
        param.height = 0;
        param.width = 0;
        ImageView v = new ImageView(this);
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_tile);
        v.setLayoutParams(param);
        layout.addView(v);
    }

}
```

As you can see there more space between tile horizontally and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewGroup root =  (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
        addCustomView(root);
}

 private void addCustomView(ViewGroup root) {
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gridLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(4);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(5);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setImageResource();
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));

                GridLayout.Spec rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f);
                GridLayout.Spec colSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f);

      GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rowSpan, colSpan
                );
    }
        root.addView(gridLayout);
```